# AFMotion and self signed certificates

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, afnetworking-2, rubymotion

I am building an ios application with Rubymotion. I do intend to use a self signed certificate for my development purposes. I would like to know whether its possible to tell the application which is the certificate thats to be used.

I have seen examples in Objective - C where the ssl certificate is ignored when an ssl challenge is raised, but even thats not what I what like to do. What i intend to do is a certificate pinning thing but with my self signed certificate.

Can any please let me know how to do this using the AFMotion library in RubyMotion or may be even using Objective -C which could check for as a reference.

Comment: *"or... even using Objective -C which could check for as a reference"* - See OWASP's [Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning). It has an Objective C example that fetches bytes from `random.org`. It pins the site's certificate in `-didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`. You can also accept a self signed with the same logic.

Comment: I have quite a few methods making external api calls. Where it would be best to put this delegate method in the code? Any suggestions?